# Menu Jquery up and down many times

Tags: jquery, menu

I have this menu animated with Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $(".submenu").slideUp(100, function(){
                $(".menu_item").css({overflow:'visible'})
            });
            $(".submenu").css({display:'none'});
            $(".menu_item").hover(function( {
                $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
                    marginTop: "0px"
                }, 300, function() {
                    //if($(".submenu", this).queue().length < 2)
                    $(".submenu", this).slideDown(300);
                });
            }, function() {
                $(".submenu", this).stop(true, true).slideUp(300, function () {
                    $(this).parent().animate({
                        marginTop: "20px"
                    }, 300);
                });
            });
    });
```

and html

```
<div id="navigation">

            <a href="" class="single">Home</a>

            <div class="menu_item">Azienda
            <div class="submenu"> 
                <a href="#">Link</a> 
                <a href="#">Link</a> 
                <a href="#">Link</a> 
            </div> 
        </div> 

        <div class="menu_item">Servizi
            <div class="submenu"> 
                <a href="#">Link</a> 
                <a href="#">Link</a> 
                <a href="#">Link</a> 
            </div> 
        </div> 

    </div><!--end navigation-->
```

,but:

there is a small "bug" with this, if you hover the mouse over the drop down menu more than once, the menu will keep going up and down the number of times you hovered over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey there, this seems to work ok for me:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".submenu").slideUp(100, function() {
            $(".menu_item").css({overflow:'visible'})
        });
        $(".submenu").css({display:'none'});
        $(".menu_item").hover(function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({
                marginTop: "0px"
            }, 300, function() {
                $(".submenu", this).stop().slideDown(300);
            });
        }, function() {
            $(".submenu", this).stop().slideUp(300, function () {
                $(this).parent().stop().animate({
                    marginTop: "20px"
                }, 300);
            });
        }
    );

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="navigation">

            <a href="" class="single">Home</a>

            <div class="menu_item">Azienda
            <div class="submenu"> 
                <a href="#">Link</a> 
                <a href="#">Link</a> 
                <a href="#">Link</a> 
            </div> 
        </div> 

        <div class="menu_item">Servizi
            <div class="submenu"> 
                <a href="#">Link</a> 
                <a href="#">Link</a> 
                <a href="#">Link</a> 
            </div> 
        </div> 

    </div><!--end navigation-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without entering into the specific code, you can set some 'status variables', something like (pseudo-code):

```
var is_open = false;
if (mouseover && !is_open) {
    // start_animation and set is_open = true when_finished
}
// Same for closing
....
```